# How, using CSS, correctly place container centered at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

My goal is to place the text (in the example below - "Publisher's Name") at the bottom of the page, while aligning it at the center.

Problem is, for some reason, the block with this text is being moved outside of the boundaries of the `<body>`. Therefore, when I try to set the `margin` for the whole page (`<body>`), it is calculated incorrectly, i.e. not includes this bottom text.

Question: what should be the correct CSS code that achieves my goal?

Code I'm currently trying:

```html
<body style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid black; margin: 50px;">
  <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 300%;">Book<br/> Title</h1>
  
  <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
    <img alt="Logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="height: 2.5em; width: auto;" />
    <br/> Publisher's
    <br/> Name
    <br/> 2018
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Your goal isn't entirely clear. How should the fixed content be positioned with respect to the black border? Why are you positioning it separately? (That's what fixed position does.) Also, inline styles are a nightmare for you and for us and for anyone yet to come. Please use CSS classes instead.

Comment: You can see from all the comments you've had to leave below that there's confusion and ambiguity. Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. The goal is rather simple: to make it look like a front page of a book with title in the middle/top side of the page and publisher name at the bottom. Then I wanted to apply margin to that page, but margin wasn't calculated correctly, because bottom text was out of the 'body' container.

As for inline CSS, I took a note and will try to use classes instead in the future. I just was lazy and thought it doesn't worth it for single class appearance.

Comment: Don't tell us down here. _Revise your question_. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you well observed: the `margin` is 2x`50px`, and with the `border`2x `5px` they together add up `110px`. So, I used the `calc()` CSS function for the centering not to slip to the right, since the margin starts from the left. This is because the `margin` on the `body` offsets the content from the browser's viewport.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
  position: absolute;
  /*min-height: 300px;  or more, to make is enjoyable on smaller screens*/
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 300%;
}

p {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Book<br/> Title
  </h1>
  <p><img alt="Logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /><br/> Publisher's
    <br/> Name
    <br/> 2018
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done like this, no transform needed.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Your text, left aligned<br> and centered</p>
<div>
```

Also: Think about putting your CSS into a .css file, inline css isn't really a good way ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in your example bottom block ("Publisher's Name") is still shown outside of the border of 'body' element. I need it to be within 'body' element, so that I can apply margin for the whole page ('body') correctly. As for .css file, I thought its needed only when same styles used elsewhere on other pages, otherwise I think it makes size of a page unnecessary bloated, because you will need to add class names etc.

Comment: This happens because of position:fixed, which will break the container out of the body. You could use position:absolute instead, but it really depends on your whole layout if you want this. Fixed stays on the bottom of the browser window, no matter what. I would just add the same margin to the .footer class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style>
body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 3em; 
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 300%;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5; 
}

p img {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in your example "Publisher's Name" text is not at the bottom of the page. And I need it to be positioned at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to position not relative to the page, but relative to the body element?
You also don't need to use transformation when it's not needed here.

```html
<body style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid black; margin: 50px;position:relative;padding-bottom:100px">
  <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 300%;">Book<br/> Title</h1>
  
  <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right:0; margin:auto; padding: 15px;">
    <img alt="Logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="height: 2.5em; width: auto;" />
    <br/> Publisher's
    <br/> Name
    <br/> 2018
  </p>
</body>
```